# Adding doubles and complex numbers in C++

Tags: c++

Consider this bit of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
  std::complex<double> z1 = 5;
  std::cout << z1 - 1 << "\n";  // must change to z1 - 1.0 to compile

  std::complex<int> z2 = 5;
  std::cout << z2 - 1.0 << "\n";  // must change to z2 - 1 to compile
}
```

This produces a compilation error, as no `operator-` is found for types in the expressions `z1 - 1` or `z2 - 1.0`.  On the other hand, changing these expressions so that the base types match works fine.

Naively, for `z1 - 1` I would expect the `int` 1 to be promoted to a `double`, and expected the `z2`, with base type `int`, in `z2 - 1.0` to be promoted to a `complex<double>`.  What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`operator-`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith3) you're trying to invoke is a function template with a single type template parameter.

```
template< class T >
complex<T> operator-( const complex<T>& lhs, const T& rhs);
```

Neither of the template parameters in the two function parameters appears in a non-deduced context, so template argument deduction is performed on both parameters individually, and this results in the `T` for `lhs` being deduced as `double`, while that for `rhs` is deduced as `int`.

Due to this mismatch between the deduced types, template argument deduction fails, and your code doesn't compile.

Comment: I usually use `std::identity<T>::type` to suppress the deduction on subsequent parameters, I find that works much better for cases very much like this one. I wonder why they didn't do this in the standard? Maybe they would take it as a defect but there could be some deeper reason why they didn't do it that way.

Comment: @VoidStar Not sure what the history is, but `complex` has been around since C++98, so it could just be that no one thought of it back then. Interestingly, there is a [converting constructor template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/complex) defined, so by extension, you'd think `operator-` would be defined with 2 different template parameters too.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will not automatically convert types from A to B to C if A is integral and B is floating-point. You want the compiler to convert from `int` -> `double` -> `complex<double>`, but it won't do that.

For the second example, you would need to promote the `complex<int>` to a `complex<double>`, which is not automatically handled by the `complex` class template.